# in python regex How to use * in lookahead assertion?

Tags: python, regex

I have these two string,

```
s='MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|frameLayout4|formLayout15||guiHelperMenu'

t='MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|frameLayout4|formLayout15|guiHelperMenu'
```

the only difference is the `|` and `||` part at the end of the string, how can I strip the `|guiHelperMenu` or `||guiHelperMenu` part with a regex ? So far I have tried

```
re.search('^.*(?=\|)',s).group()
'MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|frameLayout4|formLayout15|'
```

how can I make it support the case where there are two `||`? and return `'MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|frameLayout4|formLayout15` in both cases ?

edit:
I figured it out two minutes after posting this ... 
http://rubular.com/r/zcFGLxzfcu

Comment: Is ending part always a fixed string `guiHelperMenu`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to strip the `guiHelperMenu` part, you are overdoing it. Just use `re.sub`:

```
>>> re.sub('\|+guiHelperMenu$', '', s)
'MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|frameLayout4|formLayout15'
>>> re.sub('\|+guiHelperMenu$', '', t)
'MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|frameLayout4|formLayout15'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex for `sub`:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\|+[^|]+$', '', s)
'MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|frameLayout4|formLayout15'
>>> re.sub(r'\|+[^|]+$', '', t)
'MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|frameLayout4|formLayout15'
```

Or using `search`:

```
>>> re.search(r'.*?(?=\|+[^|]*$)', s).group()
'MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|frameLayout4|formLayout15'
>>> re.search(r'.*?(?=\|+[^|]*$)', t).group()
'MayaWindow|toolBar2|MainShelfLayout|formLayout14|frameLayout4|formLayout15'
```

---

To get the last part you can use a capturing group, that will return same string from both the inputs:

```
>>> re.search(r'\|([^|]+)$', s).group(1)
'guiHelperMenu'
>>> re.search(r'\|([^|]+)$', t).group(1)
'guiHelperMenu'
```

Or else use a lookbehind regex:

```
>>> re.search(r'(?<=\|)[^|]+$', s).group()
'guiHelperMenu'
>>> re.search(r'(?<=\|)[^|]+$', t).group()
'guiHelperMenu'
```

Comment: thanks! I got it working, although what I want is the beginning part of the string.

Comment: `re.search(r'.*[^|](?=\|)', s).group()` will also work btw